# Don't want to split if it is a number

Tags: java, regex, apache-poi

I have a string `myString = ""Ted", "Male", "29", "10,000""` . I am trying to split this string with `myString.split(",")` and write it in excel using poi. But it also splits the salary `"10,000"` to `["10","000"]`.

Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the numbers would be at end?

Comment: `myString = ""Ted", "Male", "29", "10,000""` don't make sense. Correct it. Did you mean `myString = "\"Ted\", \"Male\", \"29\", \"10,000\""`

Comment: Please confirm that you actually have `"` (quotes) around numeric fields.

Answer (score 2):

If your string is formated with a space after "," you can use this code.

```
String string = "\"Ted\", \"Male\", \"29\", \"10,000\"";

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(string.split(", ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `String.split()` function actually takes two parameters, the first is the regex to split the String with, and the second is the limit at which to stop spliting. [[Documentation]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

If you are sure that the number would always appear at the end, you can provide 3 as the input to the second parameter so that java stops splitting at 3rd comma and don't split anymore.

Example -

```
String myString = "\"Ted\", \"Male\", \"29\", \"10,000\"";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myString.split(",",3)));
>>> ["Ted",  "Male",  "29", "10,000"]
```

Comment: it will cause problem if the string have value like ""Ted", "Male", "29", "10,000, 10""

Comment: What kind of a number is that? If he wants to write it to a excel, he should have some standard structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookbehind regex to only split at commas that occur after a quote, followed by zero or more spaces:

```
String myString = "\"Ted\", \"Male\", \"29\", \"10,000\"";
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(myString.split("(?<=\"), *")));
```

output:

```
["Ted", "Male", "29", "10,000"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
(?:\\")(,\\s*)
```

It will look for  character next to  and supports zero or more spaces.

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/DfzOqVStx2)

Comment: Not able to put this regex inside split

Comment: whar about now? escaped slashes.